# How to store html2pdf library's output to a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf library to convert my webpage to a pdf. However, I do not know how to store the pdf in a variable so that I can send it back to the server. This code prints a new pdf but does not store the value to doc.

```
var doc = html2pdf(element, {return: true});
```

Answer (score 7):

After going through documentation and the [github page](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/blob/master/README.md) for the library , I finally got it to work using

```
let worker = await html2pdf().set(options).from(content).toPdf().output('blob').then( (data: Blob) => {
   return data
})
```

The full code is

```
...
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js'
...
@ViewChild('pdfForm', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) pdfForm: ElementRef;
...

async createCanvass() {
  const content: Element  = this.pdfForm.nativeElement
  const options = {
    filename: `invoice-#003.pdf`,
    margin: [20,20],
    image: {type: 'png', quality: 1 },
    html2canvas: { dpi: 400, letterRendering: true },
    jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'landscape' }
  }
  return {options: options, content: content}
}

async printPDF() {
  let { options, content } = await this.createCanvass()
  let worker = html2pdf().set(options).from(content).toPdf().output('blob').then( (data: Blob) => {
      return data
    })
  }
```

I should mention however that I am using Angular 8 and TypeScript with this code snippet, I don't think the implementation will be exactly the same with Node.js and JavaScript.

Comment: `.then(data => data)` is a no-op, it should be removed. In fact, the value isn't even used anywhere because `worker` is not returned, so the whole `printPDF` function does effectively nothing. You should `return worker`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var worker = html2pdf()
```

html2pdf() returns new Worker object. You can use method called output to get the data.
See : https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/blob/master/README.md